# Distribution of large set of fold changes

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, bioinformatics

My background in stats is limited to a few undergraduate classes. However, I have a question that intuitionally seems to have a statistical answer.

Let me describe my intuition first. I do systems biochemistry, where I look at all the compounds in a biochemical environment; as far as I know, they typically number somewhere between 3000 and 60,000. In the particular experiment I'm doing now, I'm looking at the same environment over a time lapse. This produces pairs of concentration data for each compound, which I'd like to describe with fold changes such that fold change=[final]/[initial]. I've then transformed the data with a log10() operation. My thought was that if the compounds are mostly independent, I should end up with some sort of symmetrical distribution resembling a t-distribution or a normal distribution. I tested this by creating a histogram of my data with a normal curve superimposed (x-axis should be labeled **log(** foldChange **)** ):

[image: x-axis is log10(foldChange)]

It might not look like a close fit due to the binning scheme, but it is. Here is a Q-Q normal plot.

[image]

Is there any way I can compare this distribution to a theoretical distribution and somehow quantify how much it differs from the distribution that would be created if the fold changes truly were random?

I can imagine doing some sort of bootstrapping looking at the distribution of random pairs of points between 0 and 1. For example, if we imagine that the average concentration of my features is 1000, a Poisson distribution with lambda=1000 is a good model for my data. The distribution of log-fold changes between random points in this distribution produces about what I'd expect to see. Here is the R code that describes what I mean:

```
#bootstrapping log(fold change) distribution based on a Poisson distribution
testDistra <- rpois(100000,1000)
testDistrb <- rpois(100000,1000)
testDistrPois <- data.frame(testDistra, testDistrb)
fcs <- apply(testDistrPois, 1, function(y) log10(y[2]/y[1]))
hist(fcs, breaks=100, main="Distribution of fold changes in Poisson distribution with lambda=1000", xlab="log10(foldChanges", ylab="freq")
```

It looks like this in case you don't feel like running the code yourself:
[image]

The problem is that I don't really know how to compare that to my actual distribution in a quantitative way. Is there some sort of p-value that can be generated? (I know all of us idiot biologists ask that question, but is there? haha.)

Any ideas on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Your Q-Q plot does a great job of answering your question.  It detects a heavy right tail out beyond the 98th percentile or so and shows you how that tail varies from (log)normal.  This is more than you would obtain from any formal statistical test, which will provide only a test statistic (a single number) and a p-value.